# задать owl-dots отдельному блоку

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Нужно задать owl-dots отдельному диву

```
        <div class="catalog-burgers owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="burger-block">
            <img src="static/images/burgeritem.png" data-fancybox alt="" data-caption="">
            <svg width="120" height="20" viewBox="0 0 120 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M109.665 2.5035L111.752 6.10098C111.906 6.36162 112.2 6.54262 112.538 6.58285L117.227 7.16848C117.501 7.20147 117.749 7.32535 117.917 7.5144C118.083 7.70103 118.154 7.93753 118.114 8.17002C118.081 8.36309 117.975 8.54167 117.813 8.67843L114.415 11.5028C114.167 11.6999 114.054 11.9919 114.114 12.2775L114.951 16.2483C115.04 16.7277 114.67 17.1798 114.114 17.2707C113.886 17.3021 113.651 17.2691 113.445 17.179L109.263 15.3103C108.952 15.1759 108.586 15.1759 108.275 15.3103L104.093 17.179C103.579 17.4131 102.943 17.2538 102.657 16.8194C102.551 16.6465 102.513 16.4494 102.548 16.2571L103.384 12.2856C103.444 12.0008 103.331 11.7072 103.083 11.5101L99.6861 8.68728C99.2819 8.35263 99.2697 7.80158 99.6589 7.45487C99.6673 7.44763 99.6767 7.43958 99.6861 7.43154C99.8473 7.29076 100.059 7.20147 100.288 7.17814L104.977 6.5917C105.314 6.55067 105.608 6.37128 105.762 6.10903L107.775 2.5035C107.954 2.19459 108.325 2.00233 108.728 2.01037H108.854C109.204 2.04657 109.508 2.2324 109.665 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M108.742 15.2101C108.561 15.2149 108.384 15.2568 108.225 15.3316L104.063 17.1961C103.554 17.4045 102.944 17.2428 102.659 16.8251C102.553 16.6545 102.515 16.459 102.55 16.2675L103.382 12.3043C103.438 12.0163 103.325 11.7234 103.081 11.5206L99.6822 8.6985C99.2788 8.35972 99.2713 7.80367 99.6663 7.45685C99.6719 7.45202 99.6766 7.448 99.6822 7.44397C99.8432 7.30718 100.051 7.21705 100.275 7.18888L104.967 6.59663C105.307 6.55961 105.602 6.37775 105.752 6.11381L107.791 2.4629C107.985 2.16838 108.357 1.99296 108.75 2.01146C108.742 2.25046 108.742 15.0476 108.742 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M85.8134 2.5035L87.6688 6.10098C87.8055 6.36162 88.0664 6.54262 88.3673 6.58285L92.5348 7.16848C92.7782 7.20147 92.9991 7.32535 93.1483 7.5144C93.2958 7.70103 93.3592 7.93753 93.3233 8.17002C93.2942 8.36309 93.2 8.54167 93.0558 8.67843L90.036 11.5028C89.8151 11.6999 89.7151 11.9919 89.7684 12.2775L90.5119 16.2483C90.5911 16.7277 90.2618 17.1798 89.7684 17.2707C89.565 17.3021 89.3567 17.2691 89.1733 17.179L85.4558 15.3103C85.1799 15.1759 84.854 15.1759 84.5781 15.3103L80.8607 17.179C80.4039 17.4131 79.8379 17.2538 79.5837 16.8194C79.4895 16.6465 79.4562 16.4494 79.487 16.2571L80.2305 12.2856C80.2839 12.0008 80.183 11.7072 79.963 11.5101L76.9432 8.68728C76.5839 8.35263 76.5731 7.80158 76.919 7.45487C76.9265 7.44763 76.9348 7.43958 76.9432 7.43154C77.0865 7.29076 77.2749 7.20147 77.4783 7.17814L81.6458 6.5917C81.9459 6.55067 82.2068 6.37128 82.3443 6.10903L84.133 2.5035C84.2922 2.19459 84.6223 2.00233 84.9807 2.01037H85.0924C85.4033 2.04657 85.6742 2.2324 85.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M84.9931 15.2101C84.8317 15.2149 84.6745 15.2568 84.533 15.3316L80.8337 17.1961C80.3811 17.4045 79.8394 17.2428 79.5857 16.8251C79.4916 16.6545 79.4575 16.459 79.4892 16.2675L80.228 12.3043C80.2779 12.0163 80.1781 11.7234 79.9609 11.5206L76.9398 8.6985C76.5811 8.35972 76.5745 7.80367 76.9256 7.45685C76.9306 7.45202 76.9348 7.448 76.9398 7.44397C77.0829 7.30718 77.2676 7.21705 77.4664 7.18888L81.6375 6.59663C81.9395 6.55961 82.2016 6.37775 82.3348 6.11381L84.1478 2.4629C84.32 2.16838 84.6503 1.99296 84.9998 2.01146C84.9932 2.25046 84.9931 15.0476 84.9931 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M60.8134 2.5035L62.6688 6.10098C62.8055 6.36162 63.0664 6.54262 63.3673 6.58285L67.5348 7.16848C67.7782 7.20147 67.9991 7.32535 68.1483 7.5144C68.2958 7.70103 68.3592 7.93753 68.3233 8.17002C68.2942 8.36309 68.2 8.54167 68.0558 8.67843L65.036 11.5028C64.8151 11.6999 64.7151 11.9919 64.7684 12.2775L65.5119 16.2483C65.5911 16.7277 65.2618 17.1798 64.7684 17.2707C64.565 17.3021 64.3567 17.2691 64.1733 17.179L60.4558 15.3103C60.1799 15.1759 59.854 15.1759 59.5781 15.3103L55.8607 17.179C55.4039 17.4131 54.8379 17.2538 54.5837 16.8194C54.4895 16.6465 54.4562 16.4494 54.487 16.2571L55.2305 12.2856C55.2839 12.0008 55.183 11.7072 54.963 11.5101L51.9432 8.68728C51.5839 8.35263 51.5731 7.80158 51.919 7.45487C51.9265 7.44763 51.9348 7.43958 51.9432 7.43154C52.0865 7.29076 52.2749 7.20147 52.4783 7.17814L56.6458 6.5917C56.9459 6.55067 57.2068 6.37128 57.3443 6.10903L59.133 2.5035C59.2922 2.19459 59.6223 2.00233 59.9807 2.01037H60.0924C60.4033 2.04657 60.6742 2.2324 60.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M59.9931 15.2101C59.8317 15.2149 59.6745 15.2568 59.533 15.3316L55.8337 17.1961C55.3811 17.4045 54.8394 17.2428 54.5857 16.8251C54.4916 16.6545 54.4575 16.459 54.4892 16.2675L55.228 12.3043C55.2779 12.0163 55.1781 11.7234 54.9609 11.5206L51.9398 8.6985C51.5811 8.35972 51.5745 7.80367 51.9256 7.45685C51.9306 7.45202 51.9348 7.448 51.9398 7.44397C52.0829 7.30718 52.2676 7.21705 52.4664 7.18888L56.6375 6.59663C56.9395 6.55961 57.2016 6.37775 57.3348 6.11381L59.1478 2.4629C59.32 2.16838 59.6503 1.99296 59.9998 2.01146C59.9932 2.25046 59.9931 15.0476 59.9931 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M35.8134 2.5035L37.6688 6.10098C37.8055 6.36162 38.0664 6.54262 38.3673 6.58285L42.5349 7.16848C42.7782 7.20147 42.9991 7.32535 43.1483 7.5144C43.2959 7.70103 43.3592 7.93753 43.3234 8.17002C43.2942 8.36309 43.2 8.54167 43.0558 8.67843L40.036 11.5028C39.8151 11.6999 39.7151 11.9919 39.7684 12.2775L40.5119 16.2483C40.5911 16.7277 40.2619 17.1798 39.7684 17.2707C39.5651 17.3021 39.3567 17.2691 39.1733 17.179L35.4558 15.3103C35.18 15.1759 34.854 15.1759 34.5782 15.3103L30.8607 17.179C30.4039 17.4131 29.838 17.2538 29.5838 16.8194C29.4896 16.6465 29.4562 16.4494 29.4871 16.2571L30.2306 12.2856C30.2839 12.0008 30.183 11.7072 29.963 11.5101L26.9432 8.68728C26.5839 8.35263 26.5731 7.80158 26.919 7.45487C26.9265 7.44763 26.9348 7.43958 26.9432 7.43154C27.0865 7.29076 27.2749 7.20147 27.4783 7.17814L31.6459 6.5917C31.9459 6.55067 32.2068 6.37128 32.3443 6.10903L34.1331 2.5035C34.2923 2.19459 34.6223 2.00233 34.9807 2.01037H35.0924C35.4033 2.04657 35.6742 2.2324 35.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M34.9932 15.2101C34.8318 15.2149 34.6745 15.2568 34.5331 15.3316L30.8338 17.1961C30.3811 17.4045 29.8395 17.2428 29.5857 16.8251C29.4917 16.6545 29.4576 16.459 29.4892 16.2675L30.228 12.3043C30.278 12.0163 30.1781 11.7234 29.961 11.5206L26.9398 8.6985C26.5812 8.35972 26.5745 7.80367 26.9256 7.45685C26.9306 7.45202 26.9348 7.448 26.9398 7.44397C27.0829 7.30718 27.2676 7.21705 27.4665 7.18888L31.6375 6.59663C31.9396 6.55961 32.2017 6.37775 32.3348 6.11381L34.1478 2.4629C34.3201 2.16838 34.6504 1.99296 34.9998 2.01146C34.9932 2.25046 34.9932 15.0476 34.9932 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M12.1651 2.5035L14.2524 6.10098C14.4062 6.36162 14.6997 6.54262 15.0382 6.58285L19.7267 7.16848C20.0005 7.20147 20.249 7.32535 20.4169 7.5144C20.5828 7.70103 20.6541 7.93753 20.6138 8.17002C20.581 8.36309 20.475 8.54167 20.3128 8.67843L16.9155 11.5028C16.667 11.6999 16.5545 11.9919 16.6145 12.2775L17.4509 16.2483C17.54 16.7277 17.1696 17.1798 16.6145 17.2707C16.3857 17.3021 16.1513 17.2691 15.945 17.179L11.7628 15.3103C11.4524 15.1759 11.0858 15.1759 10.7754 15.3103L6.59328 17.179C6.07942 17.4131 5.44272 17.2538 5.15672 16.8194C5.05076 16.6465 5.01325 16.4494 5.04795 16.2571L5.88438 12.2856C5.94439 12.0008 5.83093 11.7072 5.58337 11.5101L2.18608 8.68728C1.78193 8.35263 1.76974 7.80158 2.15889 7.45487C2.16733 7.44763 2.17671 7.43958 2.18608 7.43154C2.34737 7.29076 2.55929 7.20147 2.78809 7.17814L7.47659 6.5917C7.81417 6.55067 8.10767 6.37128 8.26239 6.10903L10.2747 2.5035C10.4538 2.19459 10.8251 2.00233 11.2283 2.01037H11.354C11.7038 2.04657 12.0085 2.2324 12.1651 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M11.2423 15.2101C11.0607 15.2149 10.8838 15.2568 10.7247 15.3316L6.56299 17.1961C6.05378 17.4045 5.44441 17.2428 5.15891 16.8251C5.05314 16.6545 5.01476 16.459 5.05033 16.2675L5.88154 12.3043C5.93771 12.0163 5.82538 11.7234 5.58107 11.5206L2.18226 8.6985C1.77882 8.35972 1.77133 7.80367 2.16635 7.45685C2.17196 7.45202 2.17664 7.448 2.18226 7.44397C2.34326 7.30718 2.55106 7.21705 2.77478 7.18888L7.46722 6.59663C7.80701 6.55961 8.10187 6.37775 8.25163 6.11381L10.2913 2.4629C10.4851 2.16838 10.8567 1.99296 11.2498 2.01146C11.2423 2.25046 11.2423 15.0476 11.2423 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              </svg>              
            <div class="burger-text">
              <h5>Cheeseburger With Salad</h5>
              <span>$18.00</span>
              <a class="btn-burger" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="burger-block">
            <img src="static/images/burgeritem.png" data-fancybox alt="" data-caption="">
            <div class="burger-text">
              <svg width="95" height="20" viewBox="0 0 95 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M85.8134 2.5035L87.6688 6.10098C87.8055 6.36162 88.0664 6.54262 88.3673 6.58285L92.5348 7.16848C92.7782 7.20147 92.9991 7.32535 93.1483 7.5144C93.2958 7.70103 93.3592 7.93753 93.3233 8.17002C93.2942 8.36309 93.2 8.54167 93.0558 8.67843L90.036 11.5028C89.8151 11.6999 89.7151 11.9919 89.7684 12.2775L90.5119 16.2483C90.5911 16.7277 90.2618 17.1798 89.7684 17.2707C89.565 17.3021 89.3567 17.2691 89.1733 17.179L85.4558 15.3103C85.1799 15.1759 84.854 15.1759 84.5781 15.3103L80.8607 17.179C80.4039 17.4131 79.8379 17.2538 79.5837 16.8194C79.4895 16.6465 79.4562 16.4494 79.487 16.2571L80.2305 12.2856C80.2839 12.0008 80.183 11.7072 79.963 11.5101L76.9432 8.68728C76.5839 8.35263 76.5731 7.80158 76.919 7.45487C76.9265 7.44763 76.9348 7.43958 76.9432 7.43154C77.0865 7.29076 77.2749 7.20147 77.4783 7.17814L81.6458 6.5917C81.9459 6.55067 82.2068 6.37128 82.3443 6.10903L84.133 2.5035C84.2922 2.19459 84.6223 2.00233 84.9807 2.01037H85.0924C85.4033 2.04657 85.6742 2.2324 85.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M84.9931 15.2101C84.8317 15.2149 84.6745 15.2568 84.533 15.3316L80.8337 17.1961C80.3811 17.4045 79.8394 17.2428 79.5857 16.8251C79.4916 16.6545 79.4575 16.459 79.4892 16.2675L80.228 12.3043C80.2779 12.0163 80.1781 11.7234 79.9609 11.5206L76.9398 8.6985C76.5811 8.35972 76.5745 7.80367 76.9256 7.45685C76.9306 7.45202 76.9348 7.448 76.9398 7.44397C77.0829 7.30718 77.2676 7.21705 77.4664 7.18888L81.6375 6.59663C81.9395 6.55961 82.2016 6.37775 82.3348 6.11381L84.1478 2.4629C84.32 2.16838 84.6503 1.99296 84.9998 2.01146C84.9932 2.25046 84.9931 15.0476 84.9931 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M60.8134 2.5035L62.6688 6.10098C62.8055 6.36162 63.0664 6.54262 63.3673 6.58285L67.5348 7.16848C67.7782 7.20147 67.9991 7.32535 68.1483 7.5144C68.2958 7.70103 68.3592 7.93753 68.3233 8.17002C68.2942 8.36309 68.2 8.54167 68.0558 8.67843L65.036 11.5028C64.8151 11.6999 64.7151 11.9919 64.7684 12.2775L65.5119 16.2483C65.5911 16.7277 65.2618 17.1798 64.7684 17.2707C64.565 17.3021 64.3567 17.2691 64.1733 17.179L60.4558 15.3103C60.1799 15.1759 59.854 15.1759 59.5781 15.3103L55.8607 17.179C55.4039 17.4131 54.8379 17.2538 54.5837 16.8194C54.4895 16.6465 54.4562 16.4494 54.487 16.2571L55.2305 12.2856C55.2839 12.0008 55.183 11.7072 54.963 11.5101L51.9432 8.68728C51.5839 8.35263 51.5731 7.80158 51.919 7.45487C51.9265 7.44763 51.9348 7.43958 51.9432 7.43154C52.0865 7.29076 52.2749 7.20147 52.4783 7.17814L56.6458 6.5917C56.9459 6.55067 57.2068 6.37128 57.3443 6.10903L59.133 2.5035C59.2922 2.19459 59.6223 2.00233 59.9807 2.01037H60.0924C60.4033 2.04657 60.6742 2.2324 60.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M59.9931 15.2101C59.8317 15.2149 59.6745 15.2568 59.533 15.3316L55.8337 17.1961C55.3811 17.4045 54.8394 17.2428 54.5857 16.8251C54.4916 16.6545 54.4575 16.459 54.4892 16.2675L55.228 12.3043C55.2779 12.0163 55.1781 11.7234 54.9609 11.5206L51.9398 8.6985C51.5811 8.35972 51.5745 7.80367 51.9256 7.45685C51.9306 7.45202 51.9348 7.448 51.9398 7.44397C52.0829 7.30718 52.2676 7.21705 52.4664 7.18888L56.6375 6.59663C56.9395 6.55961 57.2016 6.37775 57.3348 6.11381L59.1478 2.4629C59.32 2.16838 59.6503 1.99296 59.9998 2.01146C59.9932 2.25046 59.9931 15.0476 59.9931 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M35.8134 2.5035L37.6688 6.10098C37.8055 6.36162 38.0664 6.54262 38.3673 6.58285L42.5349 7.16848C42.7782 7.20147 42.9991 7.32535 43.1483 7.5144C43.2959 7.70103 43.3592 7.93753 43.3234 8.17002C43.2942 8.36309 43.2 8.54167 43.0558 8.67843L40.036 11.5028C39.8151 11.6999 39.7151 11.9919 39.7684 12.2775L40.5119 16.2483C40.5911 16.7277 40.2619 17.1798 39.7684 17.2707C39.5651 17.3021 39.3567 17.2691 39.1733 17.179L35.4558 15.3103C35.18 15.1759 34.854 15.1759 34.5782 15.3103L30.8607 17.179C30.4039 17.4131 29.838 17.2538 29.5838 16.8194C29.4896 16.6465 29.4562 16.4494 29.4871 16.2571L30.2306 12.2856C30.2839 12.0008 30.183 11.7072 29.963 11.5101L26.9432 8.68728C26.5839 8.35263 26.5731 7.80158 26.919 7.45487C26.9265 7.44763 26.9348 7.43958 26.9432 7.43154C27.0865 7.29076 27.2749 7.20147 27.4783 7.17814L31.6459 6.5917C31.9459 6.55067 32.2068 6.37128 32.3443 6.10903L34.1331 2.5035C34.2923 2.19459 34.6223 2.00233 34.9807 2.01037H35.0924C35.4033 2.04657 35.6742 2.2324 35.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M34.9932 15.2101C34.8318 15.2149 34.6745 15.2568 34.5331 15.3316L30.8338 17.1961C30.3811 17.4045 29.8395 17.2428 29.5857 16.8251C29.4917 16.6545 29.4576 16.459 29.4892 16.2675L30.228 12.3043C30.278 12.0163 30.1781 11.7234 29.961 11.5206L26.9398 8.6985C26.5812 8.35972 26.5745 7.80367 26.9256 7.45685C26.9306 7.45202 26.9348 7.448 26.9398 7.44397C27.0829 7.30718 27.2676 7.21705 27.4665 7.18888L31.6375 6.59663C31.9396 6.55961 32.2017 6.37775 32.3348 6.11381L34.1478 2.4629C34.3201 2.16838 34.6504 1.99296 34.9998 2.01146C34.9932 2.25046 34.9932 15.0476 34.9932 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M12.1651 2.5035L14.2524 6.10098C14.4062 6.36162 14.6997 6.54262 15.0382 6.58285L19.7267 7.16848C20.0005 7.20147 20.249 7.32535 20.4169 7.5144C20.5828 7.70103 20.6541 7.93753 20.6138 8.17002C20.581 8.36309 20.475 8.54167 20.3128 8.67843L16.9155 11.5028C16.667 11.6999 16.5545 11.9919 16.6145 12.2775L17.4509 16.2483C17.54 16.7277 17.1696 17.1798 16.6145 17.2707C16.3857 17.3021 16.1513 17.2691 15.945 17.179L11.7628 15.3103C11.4524 15.1759 11.0858 15.1759 10.7754 15.3103L6.59328 17.179C6.07942 17.4131 5.44272 17.2538 5.15672 16.8194C5.05076 16.6465 5.01325 16.4494 5.04795 16.2571L5.88438 12.2856C5.94439 12.0008 5.83093 11.7072 5.58337 11.5101L2.18608 8.68728C1.78193 8.35263 1.76974 7.80158 2.15889 7.45487C2.16733 7.44763 2.17671 7.43958 2.18608 7.43154C2.34737 7.29076 2.55929 7.20147 2.78809 7.17814L7.47659 6.5917C7.81417 6.55067 8.10767 6.37128 8.26239 6.10903L10.2747 2.5035C10.4538 2.19459 10.8251 2.00233 11.2283 2.01037H11.354C11.7038 2.04657 12.0085 2.2324 12.1651 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
                <path d="M11.2423 15.2101C11.0607 15.2149 10.8838 15.2568 10.7247 15.3316L6.56299 17.1961C6.05378 17.4045 5.44441 17.2428 5.15891 16.8251C5.05314 16.6545 5.01476 16.459 5.05033 16.2675L5.88154 12.3043C5.93771 12.0163 5.82538 11.7234 5.58107 11.5206L2.18226 8.6985C1.77882 8.35972 1.77133 7.80367 2.16635 7.45685C2.17196 7.45202 2.17664 7.448 2.18226 7.44397C2.34326 7.30718 2.55106 7.21705 2.77478 7.18888L7.46722 6.59663C7.80701 6.55961 8.10187 6.37775 8.25163 6.11381L10.2913 2.4629C10.4851 2.16838 10.8567 1.99296 11.2498 2.01146C11.2423 2.25046 11.2423 15.0476 11.2423 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
                </svg>                              
              <h5>Cheeseburger With Salad</h5>
              <span>$18.00</span>
              <a class="btn-burger" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="burger-block">
            <img src="static/images/burgeritem.png" data-fancybox alt="" data-caption="">
            <svg width="70" height="20" viewBox="0 0 70 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M35.8134 2.5035L37.6688 6.10098C37.8055 6.36162 38.0664 6.54262 38.3673 6.58285L42.5349 7.16848C42.7782 7.20147 42.9991 7.32535 43.1483 7.5144C43.2959 7.70103 43.3592 7.93753 43.3234 8.17002C43.2942 8.36309 43.2 8.54167 43.0558 8.67843L40.036 11.5028C39.8151 11.6999 39.7151 11.9919 39.7684 12.2775L40.5119 16.2483C40.5911 16.7277 40.2619 17.1798 39.7684 17.2707C39.5651 17.3021 39.3567 17.2691 39.1733 17.179L35.4558 15.3103C35.18 15.1759 34.854 15.1759 34.5782 15.3103L30.8607 17.179C30.4039 17.4131 29.838 17.2538 29.5838 16.8194C29.4896 16.6465 29.4562 16.4494 29.4871 16.2571L30.2306 12.2856C30.2839 12.0008 30.183 11.7072 29.963 11.5101L26.9432 8.68728C26.5839 8.35263 26.5731 7.80158 26.919 7.45487C26.9265 7.44763 26.9348 7.43958 26.9432 7.43154C27.0865 7.29076 27.2749 7.20147 27.4783 7.17814L31.6459 6.5917C31.9459 6.55067 32.2068 6.37128 32.3443 6.10903L34.1331 2.5035C34.2923 2.19459 34.6223 2.00233 34.9807 2.01037H35.0924C35.4033 2.04657 35.6742 2.2324 35.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M34.9932 15.2101C34.8318 15.2149 34.6745 15.2568 34.5331 15.3316L30.8338 17.1961C30.3811 17.4045 29.8395 17.2428 29.5857 16.8251C29.4917 16.6545 29.4576 16.459 29.4892 16.2675L30.228 12.3043C30.278 12.0163 30.1781 11.7234 29.961 11.5206L26.9398 8.6985C26.5812 8.35972 26.5745 7.80367 26.9256 7.45685C26.9306 7.45202 26.9348 7.448 26.9398 7.44397C27.0829 7.30718 27.2676 7.21705 27.4665 7.18888L31.6375 6.59663C31.9396 6.55961 32.2017 6.37775 32.3348 6.11381L34.1478 2.4629C34.3201 2.16838 34.6504 1.99296 34.9998 2.01146C34.9932 2.25046 34.9932 15.0476 34.9932 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M60.8134 2.5035L62.6688 6.10098C62.8055 6.36162 63.0664 6.54262 63.3673 6.58285L67.5348 7.16848C67.7782 7.20147 67.9991 7.32535 68.1483 7.5144C68.2958 7.70103 68.3592 7.93753 68.3233 8.17002C68.2942 8.36309 68.2 8.54167 68.0558 8.67843L65.036 11.5028C64.8151 11.6999 64.7151 11.9919 64.7684 12.2775L65.5119 16.2483C65.5911 16.7277 65.2618 17.1798 64.7684 17.2707C64.565 17.3021 64.3567 17.2691 64.1733 17.179L60.4558 15.3103C60.1799 15.1759 59.854 15.1759 59.5781 15.3103L55.8607 17.179C55.4039 17.4131 54.8379 17.2538 54.5837 16.8194C54.4895 16.6465 54.4562 16.4494 54.487 16.2571L55.2305 12.2856C55.2839 12.0008 55.183 11.7072 54.963 11.5101L51.9432 8.68728C51.5839 8.35263 51.5731 7.80158 51.919 7.45487C51.9265 7.44763 51.9348 7.43958 51.9432 7.43154C52.0865 7.29076 52.2749 7.20147 52.4783 7.17814L56.6458 6.5917C56.9459 6.55067 57.2068 6.37128 57.3443 6.10903L59.133 2.5035C59.2922 2.19459 59.6223 2.00233 59.9807 2.01037H60.0924C60.4033 2.04657 60.6742 2.2324 60.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M59.9931 15.2101C59.8317 15.2149 59.6745 15.2568 59.533 15.3316L55.8337 17.1961C55.3811 17.4045 54.8394 17.2428 54.5857 16.8251C54.4916 16.6545 54.4575 16.459 54.4892 16.2675L55.228 12.3043C55.2779 12.0163 55.1781 11.7234 54.9609 11.5206L51.9398 8.6985C51.5811 8.35972 51.5745 7.80367 51.9256 7.45685C51.9306 7.45202 51.9348 7.448 51.9398 7.44397C52.0829 7.30718 52.2676 7.21705 52.4664 7.18888L56.6375 6.59663C56.9395 6.55961 57.2016 6.37775 57.3348 6.11381L59.1478 2.4629C59.32 2.16838 59.6503 1.99296 59.9998 2.01146C59.9932 2.25046 59.9931 15.0476 59.9931 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M12.1651 2.5035L14.2524 6.10098C14.4062 6.36162 14.6997 6.54262 15.0382 6.58285L19.7267 7.16848C20.0005 7.20147 20.249 7.32535 20.4169 7.5144C20.5828 7.70103 20.6541 7.93753 20.6138 8.17002C20.581 8.36309 20.475 8.54167 20.3128 8.67843L16.9155 11.5028C16.667 11.6999 16.5545 11.9919 16.6145 12.2775L17.4509 16.2483C17.54 16.7277 17.1696 17.1798 16.6145 17.2707C16.3857 17.3021 16.1513 17.2691 15.945 17.179L11.7628 15.3103C11.4524 15.1759 11.0858 15.1759 10.7754 15.3103L6.59328 17.179C6.07942 17.4131 5.44272 17.2538 5.15672 16.8194C5.05076 16.6465 5.01325 16.4494 5.04795 16.2571L5.88438 12.2856C5.94439 12.0008 5.83093 11.7072 5.58337 11.5101L2.18608 8.68728C1.78193 8.35263 1.76974 7.80158 2.15889 7.45487C2.16733 7.44763 2.17671 7.43958 2.18608 7.43154C2.34737 7.29076 2.55929 7.20147 2.78809 7.17814L7.47659 6.5917C7.81417 6.55067 8.10767 6.37128 8.26239 6.10903L10.2747 2.5035C10.4538 2.19459 10.8251 2.00233 11.2283 2.01037H11.354C11.7038 2.04657 12.0085 2.2324 12.1651 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M11.2423 15.2101C11.0607 15.2149 10.8838 15.2568 10.7247 15.3316L6.56299 17.1961C6.05378 17.4045 5.44441 17.2428 5.15891 16.8251C5.05314 16.6545 5.01476 16.459 5.05033 16.2675L5.88154 12.3043C5.93771 12.0163 5.82538 11.7234 5.58107 11.5206L2.18226 8.6985C1.77882 8.35972 1.77133 7.80367 2.16635 7.45685C2.17196 7.45202 2.17664 7.448 2.18226 7.44397C2.34326 7.30718 2.55106 7.21705 2.77478 7.18888L7.46722 6.59663C7.80701 6.55961 8.10187 6.37775 8.25163 6.11381L10.2913 2.4629C10.4851 2.16838 10.8567 1.99296 11.2498 2.01146C11.2423 2.25046 11.2423 15.0476 11.2423 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              </svg>
                          
            <div class="burger-text">
              <h5>Cheeseburger With Salad</h5>
              <span>$18.00</span>
              <a class="btn-burger" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="burger-block">
            <img src="static/images/burgeritem.png" data-fancybox alt="" data-caption="">
            <svg width="23" height="20" viewBox="0 0 23 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M12.1651 2.5035L14.2524 6.10098C14.4062 6.36162 14.6997 6.54262 15.0382 6.58285L19.7267 7.16848C20.0005 7.20147 20.249 7.32535 20.4169 7.5144C20.5828 7.70103 20.6541 7.93753 20.6138 8.17002C20.581 8.36309 20.475 8.54167 20.3128 8.67843L16.9155 11.5028C16.667 11.6999 16.5545 11.9919 16.6145 12.2775L17.4509 16.2483C17.54 16.7277 17.1696 17.1798 16.6145 17.2707C16.3857 17.3021 16.1513 17.2691 15.945 17.179L11.7628 15.3103C11.4524 15.1759 11.0858 15.1759 10.7754 15.3103L6.59328 17.179C6.07942 17.4131 5.44272 17.2538 5.15672 16.8194C5.05076 16.6465 5.01325 16.4494 5.04795 16.2571L5.88438 12.2856C5.94439 12.0008 5.83093 11.7072 5.58337 11.5101L2.18608 8.68728C1.78193 8.35263 1.76974 7.80158 2.15889 7.45487C2.16733 7.44763 2.17671 7.43958 2.18608 7.43154C2.34737 7.29076 2.55929 7.20147 2.78809 7.17814L7.47659 6.5917C7.81417 6.55067 8.10767 6.37128 8.26239 6.10903L10.2747 2.5035C10.4538 2.19459 10.8251 2.00233 11.2283 2.01037H11.354C11.7038 2.04657 12.0085 2.2324 12.1651 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M11.2423 15.2101C11.0607 15.2149 10.8838 15.2568 10.7247 15.3316L6.56299 17.1961C6.05378 17.4045 5.44441 17.2428 5.15891 16.8251C5.05314 16.6545 5.01476 16.459 5.05033 16.2675L5.88154 12.3043C5.93771 12.0163 5.82538 11.7234 5.58107 11.5206L2.18226 8.6985C1.77882 8.35972 1.77133 7.80367 2.16635 7.45685C2.17196 7.45202 2.17664 7.448 2.18226 7.44397C2.34326 7.30718 2.55106 7.21705 2.77478 7.18888L7.46722 6.59663C7.80701 6.55961 8.10187 6.37775 8.25163 6.11381L10.2913 2.4629C10.4851 2.16838 10.8567 1.99296 11.2498 2.01146C11.2423 2.25046 11.2423 15.0476 11.2423 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              </svg>              
            <div class="burger-text">
              <h5>Cheeseburger With Salad</h5>
              <span>$18.00</span>
              <a class="btn-burger" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="burger-block">
            <img src="static/images/burgeritem.png" data-fancybox data-caption="" alt="">
            <svg width="45" height="20" viewBox="0 0 45 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M35.8134 2.5035L37.6688 6.10098C37.8055 6.36162 38.0664 6.54262 38.3673 6.58285L42.5349 7.16848C42.7782 7.20147 42.9991 7.32535 43.1483 7.5144C43.2959 7.70103 43.3592 7.93753 43.3234 8.17002C43.2942 8.36309 43.2 8.54167 43.0558 8.67843L40.036 11.5028C39.8151 11.6999 39.7151 11.9919 39.7684 12.2775L40.5119 16.2483C40.5911 16.7277 40.2619 17.1798 39.7684 17.2707C39.5651 17.3021 39.3567 17.2691 39.1733 17.179L35.4558 15.3103C35.18 15.1759 34.854 15.1759 34.5782 15.3103L30.8607 17.179C30.4039 17.4131 29.838 17.2538 29.5838 16.8194C29.4896 16.6465 29.4562 16.4494 29.4871 16.2571L30.2306 12.2856C30.2839 12.0008 30.183 11.7072 29.963 11.5101L26.9432 8.68728C26.5839 8.35263 26.5731 7.80158 26.919 7.45487C26.9265 7.44763 26.9348 7.43958 26.9432 7.43154C27.0865 7.29076 27.2749 7.20147 27.4783 7.17814L31.6459 6.5917C31.9459 6.55067 32.2068 6.37128 32.3443 6.10903L34.1331 2.5035C34.2923 2.19459 34.6223 2.00233 34.9807 2.01037H35.0924C35.4033 2.04657 35.6742 2.2324 35.8134 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M34.9932 15.2101C34.8318 15.2149 34.6745 15.2568 34.5331 15.3316L30.8338 17.1961C30.3811 17.4045 29.8395 17.2428 29.5857 16.8251C29.4917 16.6545 29.4576 16.459 29.4892 16.2675L30.228 12.3043C30.278 12.0163 30.1781 11.7234 29.961 11.5206L26.9398 8.6985C26.5812 8.35972 26.5745 7.80367 26.9256 7.45685C26.9306 7.45202 26.9348 7.448 26.9398 7.44397C27.0829 7.30718 27.2676 7.21705 27.4665 7.18888L31.6375 6.59663C31.9396 6.55961 32.2017 6.37775 32.3348 6.11381L34.1478 2.4629C34.3201 2.16838 34.6504 1.99296 34.9998 2.01146C34.9932 2.25046 34.9932 15.0476 34.9932 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M12.1651 2.5035L14.2524 6.10098C14.4062 6.36162 14.6997 6.54262 15.0382 6.58285L19.7267 7.16848C20.0005 7.20147 20.249 7.32535 20.4169 7.5144C20.5828 7.70103 20.6541 7.93753 20.6138 8.17002C20.581 8.36309 20.475 8.54167 20.3128 8.67843L16.9155 11.5028C16.667 11.6999 16.5545 11.9919 16.6145 12.2775L17.4509 16.2483C17.54 16.7277 17.1696 17.1798 16.6145 17.2707C16.3857 17.3021 16.1513 17.2691 15.945 17.179L11.7628 15.3103C11.4524 15.1759 11.0858 15.1759 10.7754 15.3103L6.59328 17.179C6.07942 17.4131 5.44272 17.2538 5.15672 16.8194C5.05076 16.6465 5.01325 16.4494 5.04795 16.2571L5.88438 12.2856C5.94439 12.0008 5.83093 11.7072 5.58337 11.5101L2.18608 8.68728C1.78193 8.35263 1.76974 7.80158 2.15889 7.45487C2.16733 7.44763 2.17671 7.43958 2.18608 7.43154C2.34737 7.29076 2.55929 7.20147 2.78809 7.17814L7.47659 6.5917C7.81417 6.55067 8.10767 6.37128 8.26239 6.10903L10.2747 2.5035C10.4538 2.19459 10.8251 2.00233 11.2283 2.01037H11.354C11.7038 2.04657 12.0085 2.2324 12.1651 2.5035" fill="#FAC412"/>
              <path d="M11.2423 15.2101C11.0607 15.2149 10.8838 15.2568 10.7247 15.3316L6.56299 17.1961C6.05378 17.4045 5.44441 17.2428 5.15891 16.8251C5.05314 16.6545 5.01476 16.459 5.05033 16.2675L5.88154 12.3043C5.93771 12.0163 5.82538 11.7234 5.58107 11.5206L2.18226 8.6985C1.77882 8.35972 1.77133 7.80367 2.16635 7.45685C2.17196 7.45202 2.17664 7.448 2.18226 7.44397C2.34326 7.30718 2.55106 7.21705 2.77478 7.18888L7.46722 6.59663C7.80701 6.55961 8.10187 6.37775 8.25163 6.11381L10.2913 2.4629C10.4851 2.16838 10.8567 1.99296 11.2498 2.01146C11.2423 2.25046 11.2423 15.0476 11.2423 15.2101" fill="#FAC412"/>
              </svg>              
            <div class="burger-text">
              <h5>Cheeseburger With Salad</h5>
              <span>$18.00</span>
              <a class="btn-burger" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-burger"> 
          <img class="arrow-left" src="static/images/arrow.svg" alt="">
          <div class="slider-navigation">
            <div   role="button" class="slider-btn"></div>
            <div  role="button" class="slider-btn"></div>
            <div  role="button" class="slider-btn"></div>
            <div  role="button" class="slider-btn"></div>
          </div>
          <img class="arrow-right" src="static/images/arrow.svg" alt="">
        </div>
```

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var owl = $(".owl-carousel")

      owl.owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        dots:true,
        nav:false,
        loop:true
      })
    $('.arrow-right').click(function() {
      owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    })
    $('.arrow-left').click(function() {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
})
  });
  
  </script>
```

[image: Эти точки должны быть связаны с слайдером]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создать отдельный div с классом "owl-dots".
2. Поместить div внутрь блока "catalog-burgers" перед блоком "slider-burger".
3. Изменить параметры инициализации owl-carousel, для указания нового элемента для owl-dots.

```html
<div class="catalog-burgers owl-carousel owl-theme">
  ...
</div>
<div class="owl-dots"></div>
<div class="slider-burger">
  ...
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel")

    owl.owlCarousel({
      items:5,
      dots:false,
      nav:false,
      loop:true
    })

    // Инициализация owl-dots
    var dots = $(".owl-dots")

    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
      dots.empty() // очистить owl-dots перед добавлением новых элементов

      var current = event.item.index // текущий элемент
      var total = event.item.count // всего элементов

      for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var dot = $("<div>").addClass("owl-dot")

        if (i === current) {
          dot.addClass("active")
        }

        dots.append(dot)
      }
    })

    $('.arrow-right').click(function() {
      owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    })

    $('.arrow-left').click(function() {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Кнопки при добавлении стилей появляются, но не работают